# EXECUTE IMMEDIATE PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

Let's say sStorecode is: 00020

The following just executes the select statement to get the accountid at another database STORE in the table STOREINFO, for example connecting to p008081 (where 008 is the substring of the sStorecode and 081 is what I am joining below), 
but I am getting errors for some reason (Invalid SQL Statement), can someone help?

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select AccountID from STOREINFO@STORE.p'||substr(sSTORECODE,3,3)||'081';
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So is `STOREINFO` the name of the table, or is the table named `p008081`?

Answer (score 2):

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is a PL/SQL command. In PL/SQL, the result of a SELECT statement needs to go somewhere. But it your statement, you don't specify where it should go.

So if you expect a single row, you could write:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select AccountID from STOREINFO@STORE.p'||substr(sSTORECODE,3,3)||'081'
    INTO l_account_id;
```

`l_account_id` is a local PL/SQL variable.

If you expect several row, you could use

```
EXECUTE IMMEDATE ... BULK COLLECT INTO l_account_tab;
```

`l_account_tab` is a PL/SQL collection variable.

Or if you want to work with cursors, you can write:

```
 OPEN account_id_cv FOR 'select AccountID from STOREINFO@STORE.p'||substr(sSTORECODE,3,3)||'081';
```

`account_id_cv` is a REF CURSOR variable.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that should be something like this instead:

```
'select AccountID from STORE.STOREINFO WHERE sStorecode = ''p'||substr(sSTORECODE,3,3)||'081''';
```

Comment: In PL/SQL, the backslash doesn't work as an escape characters. If you want to *escape* a quote, you need to double it. But if I'm not mistaken, user1941350 has to deal with rather dynamic table names such as *p008081*. So it doesn't help anyway.

Comment: @Codo - thanks, updated my answer.  I wasn't sure about the dynamic tables since he specifically said *in the table STOREINFO*.  So the question still seems a bit unclear to me in that regard.